# How to find percentage of one rectangles area based on another rectangles area

Tags: geometry, surfaces, area

I know I might sound the dumbest person in the galaxy, but I just wanted to make sure I am doing this right.

I have a rectangle say [R1] placed inside a bigger rectangle [R2]. R1 will always be <= [R2].

In order to find what percentage of [R2] surface is occupied by [R1],I do:

```
R1Area = R1 length * R1 breadth
R2Area = R2 length * R2 breadth
PercenageArea = (R1Area/R2Area) * 100.
```

Can someone confirm if this works fine - or if we need to do anything else because we are talking about surface area of rectangles here..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is correct if $R_1$ lies completely inside $R_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly fine.

% $  \text{area occupied of rectangle }R_2 \text{by  rectangle } R_1  = \frac{\text{area of} R_1}{\text{area of} R_2} \times 100$